# What is the answer to the following puzzle?

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, computer-puzzle

Observe the following question carefully and answer accordingly.

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA8AAAAPCAYAAAA71pVKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsIAAA7CARUoSoAAAAAhSURBVDhPY3wro/KfgUzABKXJAqOaSQSjmkkEQ1IzAwMA91ACSkIHdUMAAAAASUVORK5CYII+iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA8AAAAPCAYAAAA71pVKAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAAhSURBVDhPY1Ta6POfgUzABKXJAqOaSQSjmkkEQ1IzAwMAxG8CPEsYinAAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

Comment: is it really puzzle , or you just pressed randomly on keyboard.as there are many A's U's and S's

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22413868/toastr-js-plugin-and-css-color-change

Comment: is this helpful?

Comment: If you use [this](http://base64online.org/decode/) tool to convert the string it's literally just a 15x15 red image. I don't know if it's reliable, though.

Comment: @smriti Yes, go ahead!

Comment: @LuxxMiner The odd part is that it seems to have duplicated data though.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> L

because

> This is a base64 encoded binary file that contains two png files. When viewing this in a normal viewer, it will only read the first png file, which is a red square. When the two files are shown on top of each other by a non-conforming (as in: does not follow [the specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html)) PNG viewer it will show the green square under this red square.

as shown here:

> [image]

Comment: @Samurai8 Quite close to the answer but not the correct answer yet!

Comment: I am clueless as to what you expect more as an answer. This question depends on a non-conformant image viewer. Simply overlaying them does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/qzutx783/ . There are no text blocks in the image data. There is a `CR3` sequence inside the IDAT block that is quite different from the other image. I can't find any documentation on that whatsoever though.

Comment: The L is Vladimir Lenin, of course. He's [buried in the Red Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenin%27s_Mausoleum). `:)`

Comment: That... well, that sounds like it could be an answer.